# The method method_name(FileInputStream, FileOutputStream) is undefined for the type Class_name

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, blowfish

A method I've written seems unreachable. I'm pasting the method below:

```
     public void decryt_data(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws   InvalidKeyException,  IOException {
         // initialize the cipher
          cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret_key);      
          // Bytes read from in will be decrypted
            in = new CipherInputStream(in, cipher);             
            int numRead = 0;
            while ((numRead = in.read(buf)) >= 0)
            {
                out.write(buf, 0, numRead);
            }
            out.close();
     }
```

I'm trying to call this method using an instance of the Class as follows:
                                  `encryption.decrypt_data(new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/encrypted"),new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/decrypted"));`

Eclipse tells me: The method decrypt_data(FileInputStream, FileOutputStream) is undefined for the type AES(i.e. the class name)

However the following method call works perfectly fine:

`encryption.encrypt_data(new FileInputStream(fc.getSelectedFile().getPath()),new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/encrypted"));`

Waiting for some help :D Thanks.

Comment: if you have a new question, please ask it as a separate question.  Completely changing your question disconnects it from the answers and is not helpful to people down the line

Comment: Closing it as too localized. This is not to punish you in any way, just because a spelling mistake is unlikely to help anybody else out there.

Answer (score 2):

Spelling mistake `decryt_data` should be `decrypt_data`.

Your method is called `public void decryt_data(InputStream in, OutputStream out)`, there is a `p` missing in `decryt`

Comment: Seems I need sleep now. Thanks a ton :D

Comment: it is a new problem post it as a new question and revert this question to old format

Answer (score 0):

Call decryt_data() instead of decrypt_data()